# (iOS) Will mucking about with my User-agent get my app rejected?

Tags: ios, user-agent

In my app, I use the following type of code to muck with the User-agent:

```
// Fake Firefox's user agent during web service's registration
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Windows; U; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; en-US; rv:12.0) Gecko/20120403211507 Firefox/12.0", @"UserAgent", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];

// Return to standard iOS user agent when web service registration is done
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3", @"UserAgent", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];
```

Part of my app allows the user to register for a web service using its "sign up for an account" page, and the only way I could find to prevent its website from automatically launching a page which says "DOWNLOAD OUR APP INSTEAD!" is to muck with the user-agent string thusly.  I've tried setting the User-agent in a `NSMutableURLRequest` but I have NOT gotten this to work at all. (Yes I have tried setting both "User-Agent" and "User_Agent" in the `NSMutableURLRequest`.)

I have heard that this might get your app rejected from Apple.  Can anyone confirm or deny, or offer any comment?  Thanks!

Comment: Google Chrome does it I think on iOS as you can request the desktop version of a site.

Comment: Why fake Firefox's? Why not just say "MyApp 1.0" etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There are multiple apps on the App Store that fake the user agent as well.
2. All workarounds for setting the language of NSLocalizedString set a custom value for an Apple key in the NSUserDefaults as well

So I don't think Apple will reject your app.

Answer (score 1):

We use custom user agents in our apps as a way for our servers to know that our app is calling - and to pass extra data, for example, whether the app has a retina screen. As long as you don't rely on this for *security* it works well. Nothing has ever been rejected as a result.